# Zend Framework model relationships and accessing related records

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I've got a zend framework model:

```
class User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    protected $_name    = 'users';
    protected $_primary = 'id';
    protected $_dependentTables = array('UserItem');

    public function refresh($) {
        $items = $this->findDependentRowset('UserItem', 'items');
            // do stuff with each item
        print_r($items);
        die();
    }
}
```

I've also got the related model:

```
<?php
class UserItem extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'user_items';
    protected $_referenceMap    = array(
        'items' => array(
            // user_id is the name of the field on the USER_ITEMS table
            'columns'           => 'user_id',
            'refTableClass'     => 'User',
            // id is the name of the field on the USERS table
            'refColumns'        => 'id'
        )
    );
}
```

?>

I'd like to me able to call `User->refresh();` and have a fancy little stack of things happen. But the error is

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method FbUser::findDependentRowset()
```

Which is telling me that although I *think* i'm doing it right according to the Zend documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html I'm missing something.

If it makes a difference, at first run the items list will be empty, then I'll "Upsert" a whole bunch of items - future runs I'll compare all items an only update the ones that are different.  Hmm... nope that's definitely not relevant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your classses mixed. You should have 2 classes for every entity... a EntityTable (your table gateway) and an Entity (your row gateway). so the class declarations should look something like:

```
class User extends Zend_Db_Table_Row

class FbUser extends User

class UserTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

class UserItem extends Zend_Db_Table_Row

class UserItemTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
```

The row classes are your models (or are linked to models depending on how you want to wire it up), not the table classes.

The `findDependentRowset` method is on the Zend_Db_Table_Row class which is why you are getting the error... you have extended the incorrect class in a way.

By in a way, i mean that your table definitions are correct, but you are trying to use the table instances like rows. You can either add/change class usage as suggested above or you can pass the wor instance of user to the table class as an arg ument to refresh:

```
public function refresh(Zend_Db_Table_Row $user)
{
   $items = $user->findDependentRowset('UserItem', 'items');
   // do stuff with each item
   print_r($items);
   die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working now, but makes me think there might be a more elegant way to do what I'm trying to do.